# Excel VSTO - accessing AutoFilter's Array Criteria throws exceptions

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, autofilter

I am working on a C# VSTO project in Excel that needs to save the current AutoFilter information and re-apply the filter after some table update. I have managed to have it work on simple text and number filters. But it fails on Date Filters.

On a closer look, it seems when the filter Criteria is an Array, there is no way to access the criteria? Basically, the code `myCriteria = someFilter.Criteria2`, which returns a string for simple text filters, throws a COM exception now.

The MSDN doc on this issue (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/microsoft.office.interop.excel.filter_members(v=office.14)) is not helping at all.

I tried to record the filtering in Macro, and here is the recorded code for filtering a Date column to October:

```
ActiveSheet.Range("$C$1:$C$6").AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                                          Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                                          Criteria2:=Array(1, "10/31/2013")
```

The "Criteria2" part is what I want to get via code.

Any ideas are highly appreciated!

Comment: I am not sure why the post has been downvoted, and would really appreciate the downvoter's elaboration. BTW, the issue has been confirmed on msdn forum. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/281fdbc5-6535-497f-b427-f69f4b092e24/excel-vsto-accessing-autofilters-array-criteria-throws-exceptions

Answer (score 0):

A tiny trick!

Say the filter was applied manually.  At the time you apply a filter to a column, your only options are the items in the column.  Once the filter has been applied, the only visible cells in the column are the ones selected by the filter.

Thus you can run a loop down the column, collecting the visible cells.  Then remove duplicates with a Collection or Dictionary.  What remain are the filter criteria.

Comment: Thanks! But this seems not enough, since the data in the table are dynamically updated before I try to re-apply the filter and it is not possible to re-construct the criteria the user picked from the data. For example, if the current filtered dates are all in Oct 2013, there is no way to know is that because the user picked "Oct 2013", or the user simply picked "2013" but there is just no data from other months.