# VSTO - Excel - AutoFilter - Trying to get Date filter criteria (year, month or day) throws exception

Tags: excel, date, filter, vsto, autofilter

I'm trying to get the filters of a table in order to reapply them after some modifications. Everything is ok, but the trouble begins when the filter is on a Date column. This is the way I'm doing it:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= filters.Count; i++)
{
  FilterTemp f = new FilterTemp();
  f.On = filters[i].On;

  if (f.On)
  {
    f.Field = i;

    try
    {
      f.Criteria1 = filters[i].Criteria1;
    }
    catch { }

    f.Operator = (int)filters[i].Operator;

    try
    {
      f.Criteria2 = filters[i].Criteria2;
    }
    catch { }
  }

  fs.Add(f);
}
```

When the filter is on a text or number column, everything works beautifully, but when a date column is filtered by year, month or day, I get an exception on line 5 when trying to get the "Criteria1".

I tried to change the operator to xlFilterDynamic, as mentioned on an answer of this MSDN post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/15ec8d69-3e6f-450d-82c0-ca53e63c8f64/getting-data-of-list-object-filters-for-date-column?forum=vsto

Something like this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= filters.Count; i++)
{
  FilterCache f = new FilterCache();
  f.On = filters[i].On;

  if (f.On)
  {
    f.Field = i;

    try
    {
      f.Criteria1 = filters[i].Criteria1;
    }
    catch
    {
      filters[i].Operator = XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterDynamic;

      f.Criteria1 = filters[i].Criteria1;
    }

    f.Operator = (int)filters[i].Operator;

    if (f.Operator == 0)
      f.Operator = (int)XlAutoFilterOperator.xlAnd;

    try
    {
      f.Criteria2 = filters[i].Criteria2;
    }
    catch { }
  }

  fs.Add(f);
}
```

No success. The filters[i].Criteria1 is now returning 1 forever, it doesn't matter the filter I use on that date column.

In order to simulate this issue, it is necessary to create a table on an Excel worksheet and then put some random dates in a column. Then, filter this column selecting at least 3 different dates. Run the code.

There's already a post about this on stackoverflow: [Excel VSTO - accessing AutoFilter's Array Criteria throws exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19779230/excel-vsto-accessing-autofilters-array-criteria-throws-exceptions)

Also at: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/281fdbc5-6535-497f-b427-f69f4b092e24/excel-vsto-accessing-autofilters-array-criteria-throws-exceptions

... But there are no satisfactory answers or maybe it is a little bit difficult to understand the question.

FilterTemp class:

```
public class FilterTemp
{
  public bool On;
  public object Field;
  public object Criteria1;
  public int Operator;
  public object Criteria2;
}
```

Comment: Are supporting the old binary files (xls) or 2007 and higher? I'm looking to an option getting the data from ExcelML

Comment: @PetLahev, in my case it is Excel 2010+ (.xlsx). But I'm not exporting, I'm working directly with the Excel in an AddIn programmed using VSTO.

Comment: That's OK. If my idea would work the only one thing you will have to do is adding OpenXML nuget to your project - https://www.nuget.org/packages/DocumentFormat.OpenXml/
Are you targeting .NETFramework 4.5.x?

Answer (score 0):

So this is just an **idea** The ultimate goal is to return the date back to client in a way that it can be re-applied via AutoFilter like here

```
string[] FilterList = new string[] { "10/31/2013", "5/4/2013" };
visibleCells.AutoFilter(1, FilterList.Length > 0 ? FilterList.ToArray() : Type.Missing, Excel.XlAutoFilterOperator.xlFilterValues, Type.Missing, true);
```

Hopefully this will give you a hint how to continue. I'll try to finalize it some day.
All code with example on [GitHub](https://github.com/PetLahev/ExcelAutoFilterCriteriaRetriever)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.IO;

namespace AutoFilterRetriever
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An example class how to get AutoFilter criteria from internal XML representation
    /// </summary>
    public class CriteriaFilterRetriever : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly Excel.Worksheet wks;
        private readonly string filePath;
        private Stream docStream;
        private SpreadsheetDocument openXmlDoc;
        private WorkbookPart wkb;        

        public CriteriaFilterRetriever(Excel.Worksheet sheet)
        {
            wks = sheet;
            filePath = sheet.Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName;
            if (!filePath.Contains("\\"))
            {
                throw new FileLoadException("Save the file in order to get autofilter criteria");
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// This can be changed to a complex object instead of just list of strings
        /// </summary>
        public List<string> FilterCriteria { get; private set; }

        public void GetFilterCriteria()
        {
            if (!OpenFile()) throw new FileLoadException($"Couldn't open the file - {filePath}");
            if (wks.AutoFilter == null) return;

            // here we get sheet in the workbook.xml (Equals don't work here)
            var sheetInWkb = wkb.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == wks.Name).FirstOrDefault();
            // get a reference to the worksheet part. Imagine part as the folder in the zip structure
            WorksheetPart wsPart = (WorksheetPart)(wkb.GetPartById(sheetInWkb.Id));
            // finally get the xml file e.g. sheet1.xml
            var sheet = wsPart.Worksheet;
            // there should be just one autofilter per sheet
            var filter = sheet.Descendants<AutoFilter>().First();
            if (filter == null) throw new InvalidOperationException($"Couldn't get autofilter data from the {wks.Name} sheet.");
            ManageFilterData(filter);
        }

        private void ManageFilterData(AutoFilter filter)
        {
            FilterCriteria = new List<string>();
            // this is always the first element in AutoFilter
            foreach (FilterColumn filterCol in filter)
            {
                // here we get the filters data
                var filters = filterCol.FirstChild;
                if (filters is Filters)
                {
                    foreach (var item in filters)
                    {
                        if (item is DateGroupItem)
                        {
                            FilterCriteria.Add(GetDateFilterCriteria(item as DateGroupItem));
                        }
                        else if (item is Filter)
                        {
                            FilterCriteria.Add(((Filter)item).Val);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Not sure what to do here");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else if (filters is CustomFilters)
                {
                    // if custom filter is applied (more than one criteria it falls to this category
                    foreach (var item in filters)
                    {
                        if (item is CustomFilter)
                        {
                            var tmp = item as CustomFilter;                            
                            FilterCriteria.Add($"{tmp.Operator}, {tmp.Val}");
                        }                        
                        else
                        {
                            throw new Exception("Not sure what to do here");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private string GetDateFilterCriteria(DateGroupItem criteria)
        {
            if (criteria.DateTimeGrouping == DateTimeGroupingValues.Year)
            {
                return criteria.Year.ToString();
            }
            else if (criteria.DateTimeGrouping == DateTimeGroupingValues.Month)
            {
                return $"{criteria.Year.ToString()}-{criteria.Month.ToString()}";
            }
            else if (criteria.DateTimeGrouping == DateTimeGroupingValues.Day)
            {
                return $"{criteria.Year.ToString()}-{criteria.Month.ToString()}-{criteria.Day.ToString()}";
            }
            else if (criteria.DateTimeGrouping == DateTimeGroupingValues.Hour)
            {
                return $"{criteria.Year.ToString()}-{criteria.Month.ToString()}-{criteria.Day.ToString()} {criteria.Hour.ToString()}:00:00";
            }
            else if (criteria.DateTimeGrouping == DateTimeGroupingValues.Minute)
            {
                return $"{criteria.Year.ToString()}-{criteria.Month.ToString()}-{criteria.Day.ToString()} {criteria.Hour.ToString()}:{criteria.Minute.ToString()}:00";
            }
            else
            {
                return $"{criteria.Year.ToString()}-{criteria.Month.ToString()}-{criteria.Day.ToString()} " +
                       $"{criteria.Hour.ToString()}:{criteria.Minute.ToString()}:{criteria.Second.ToString()}";
            }
        }

        /// <summary> Opens the given file via the DocumentFormat package </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        private bool OpenFile()
        {
            try
            {
                docStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite);
                openXmlDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(docStream, false);
                wkb = openXmlDoc.WorkbookPart;                
                return true;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {                
                return false;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            openXmlDoc?.Close();
            docStream?.Close();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Great idea, but unfortunately the user will almost never save the file because he has a Save button to save the data directly to the database. But anyway, thank you for the code.

Comment: Well the file does need to be saved on a disk before first use but doesn't need to be save for getting the filter data. It means it won't work if you just simply create a new workbook, add some data, apply filter and then want to use the code -> won't work. You will have save it at some point then you can change the data as you want and NOT need to save, as long as the file is in file system it will work. There is also a possibility to use SaveCopyAs. Overall I don't think you have too many options here, the Excel object model is just not ready for the multifilter criteria

Comment: I agree with you that I'm running out of options, but the files will almost never going to be saved and almost all the time there will more than one user using the same ".xlsx" file. And the most important: it is not an obligation to be ".xlsx". Sometimes it will be ".xls". Again, I appreciate you help. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Ah I see the xls would be a showstopper, the not saving problem can be solved